# Using a LAMBDA as the 2nd argument to FILTER

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

In Excel, I can easily pass a `LAMBDA` as the 2nd parameter to `MAP`, as expected:

```js
=MAP({1, 2, 3}, LAMBDA(x, x = 1))
// { TRUE, FALSE, FALSE }
```

If I try to do the same with `FILTER`, I get an error:

```js
=FILTER({1, 2, 3}, LAMBDA(x, x = 1))
// #CALC!
```

I have a few related questions:

1. Is there actually some way of using a LAMBDA as the 2nd parameter here that I'm missing?
2. The [official documentation for FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) mentions nothing about the type or any restrictions for the parameters — it simply says "based on criteria you define". Where can I find documentation for Excel formulas that explicitly gives such info (e.g. "the nth parameter must be a string", "must be an absolute reference given in R1C1 format", "must be a number between -283 and 87845", "must be a range of cells and not an array literal", "must be a range of cells or an array literal but not an array cell reference for some reason", etc etc)
3. If I can't use a LAMBDA, how would I filter an array literal?
4. Does Microsoft have any roadmap for realeasing such obviously useful features that would give the consistent API for `MAP` and `FILTER` that any sane person would expect?

If I sound salty it's because I'm salty

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can but you have to know the difference between the lambda-helper function [`MAP()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) and the actual [`LAMBDA()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function.

---

Syntax for `MAP()`:

```
=MAP(array1, lambda_or_array<#>)
```

Map is a build-in lambda helper, and since the sole function is to apply a lambda in an iterative calculation you can apply `=MAP({1,2,3},LAMBDA(x,x=1))`.

---

Syntax for creating a `LAMBDA()` in a cell as per official documentation:

```
=LAMBDA([parameter1, parameter2, ...],calculation)(function call)
```

The difference here is that with the actual lambda you still ought to create *your own custom function*. For this the syntax is a little different and in contrast to the build-in functions like `MAP()`, `REDUCE()` etc; you'd still need to somehow include the input. This is done through an extra set of paranthesis at the end of the function: `=LAMBDA(x,x=1)({1,2,3})`.¹

---

So now we know that with the build-in lambda-helpers, the input is an actual parameter within the function's syntax we could apply both to your `FILTER()`:

```
=FILTER({1,2,3},MAP({1,2,3},LAMBDA(x,x=1)))
```

Or²:

```
=FILTER({1,2,3},LAMBDA(x,x=1)({1,2,3})
```

See how the `MAP()` function does make live a little easier? One could also use `LAMBDA()` to create their own custom function as per footnote below and call it:

```
=FILTER({1,2,3},TEST({1,2,3})
```

---

¹ <sup>One would usually create a custom named lamda function in the name manager. In such cases you'd not need to include the source at the end but call the function including the input in the 1st parameter. e.g: a custom named function called `TEST()` which refers to `=LAMBDA(x,x=1)` would output `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}` when called `=TEST({1,2,3})`.</sup>

² <sup>If you do want to use array literals, consider to incorporate `LET()` to be able to chuck the array into a named variable first. e.g: `=LET(x,{1,2,3},FILTER(x,LAMBDA(y,y=1)(x)))`.</sup>

Comment: This is really a brilliant explanation :-) Regarding your footnote 2: isn't this overcomplicated? `=LET(x,{1,2,3},FILTER(x,x=1))` will do the job without LAMBDA.

Comment: @Ike, yes you can but `x=1` is the absolute easiest of calculations. If it's that simple, skip the `LET()`. The beauty of `LAMBDA()` I find is that you can have any type of calculation within that 2nd parameter, including calls to other functions etc. In such case I'd always use `LET()`.

Comment: If the range you're filtering has more than one column, this will not work and you will get a #VALUE error. The reason is that FILTER, as a second argument, expects a single-column of values that can be interpreted as true/false (or zero-nonzero).  To use this method for filtering multi-column ranges, use BYROW instead of LAMBDA.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your third question: you can use this formula:

```
=LAMBDA(x,FILTER(x,x=2))({1,2,3})
```

Or - if you want to keep the columns:

```
=BYCOL({1,2,3},LAMBDA(x,FILTER(x,x=2,"")))
```

---

enhancement to the first version to pass the filter-value:

```
=LAMBDA(arrValues, filterBy, FILTER(arrValues,arrValues = filterBy))({1,2,3};3)
```